How to make a .desktop file appear in application search?
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 and I was trying to install Arduino as an application. I'm fairly new to Linux and followed a couple of tutorials (mainly this one) but I can't achieve to make my application appear in the application searcher.
I also already set the .desktop file as trusted using
gio set arduino-ide.desktop metadata::trusted true

and made the file an executable using
chmod a+x arduino-ide.desktop

Any help?
